# How not to include a Thumb in ListBoxItem selection

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0

I have a collection of items. I am presenting the items in a WPF ListBox using `DataTemplate`. Part of the DataTemplate is a `Thumb` which is used for resizing and visually separating between items. The `Thumb.Visibility` is binded to a property of the item (for example, the last item doesn’t have a visible Thumb).

The problem is that selecting an item in the `ListBox` selects the `Thumb` as well, as it is part of the `ListBoxItem`. The desired behavior is to select only the data without the `Thumb`.
 How is it possible to get this behavior? I don’t want to add items by code the `ListBox` or to handle the visibility of the `Thumb` manually. Currently I get all this from the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this inside item container style, not DataTemplate. I.e. define your own `ListBoxItem` style and highlight only what's required. E.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
       <Grid>
        <Border 
          Name="Border"
          Margin="0, 0, 0, 1"
          Padding="2"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
         <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1" BorderBrush="Black"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
```